# Youtube direct lite giving error: uploads.gdata.youtube.com’s server IP address could not be found

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, frontend

I need to allow users to upload videos to our channel. After some search i found the youtube direct lite that looks like its the best solution. But then i tested on our site and i'm getting this error: `uploads.gdata.youtube.com’s server IP address could not be found.`
Is this project still even working?

The steps i did:

1. Log in with yt account [here](https://ytdirectlite.appspot.com/static-min/admin.html)
2. Add the iframe (a submission widget) into the page
3. Test (adding a video via the submission widget)

[image: Upload]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

'Cause of it is a project from 2012! I think this project is dead. In the description they talk about Picasa, a project that is down since 2 years. Maybe use the API [Video Insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)